# Calculating the tangent plane on a point (x, y, z) when the function given has no z?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

So I have this function that looks something like $2x^2-x-5y=17$ and I need to find out the tangent plane for this surface on the point $P=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. I understand that the gradient for a function on a point is the normal vector to the level surface on that point. Given that normal-vector I can define a plane that will be tangent to the level surface.

Now what I do not understand is that this function does not contain a z-component. And to find out the level surface for a point of a surface I basically need to take the funtion $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=C$. Am I supposed to bring the whole expression to one side, as in my example such that $2x^2-x-5y-17=0$ and then define $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=2x^2-x-5y-17$ and furthermore $f(x,y)=z$? Is this $C$ that is supposed to be $C=z_1$?

Of course the functiongraph is not equal to the function but when I plot both $2x^2-x-5y=17$ and $z=2x^2-x-5y-17$ I (as I expect) get different results in geogebra.

So my question is, how do I calculate the tangentplane on the point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ of a surface, but the function is unbound by one component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the curve $2x^2-x-5y=17$ on the plane $z=0$. Now compute the tangent *line* to that curve passing through $(x_1,y_1,0)$. You will get a line $ax+by=c$ on the plane $z=0$. Then your tangent *plane* will be the plane $ax+by=c$, which is the vertical plane containing the line that you got.

Comment: Is there not an infinite amount of lines tangent to the curve at the point $(x_1,y_1,0)$? Why should I not compute the normal vector to the curve at that point? Since I have a point and the normal I'd simply be able to define the tangent plane by the point-normal equation, correct? 

For $2x^2-x-5y=-4$ at $(1,1,z_1)$ (bad example for (=17)), calculating the gradient and excluding the z-component gives me the plane $3x-5y=-2$ which it seems to be a tangentplane to any point $(1,1,z_1)$. Is my approach/arguments faulty?

Comment: There ar infinitely many lines tangent to the curve at the point $(x_1,y_1,0)$, but only one of them is contained in the plane $z=0$.

Comment: Then, if we consider the plane $z=a$, should I still calculate the tangent line? I understand your explanation, but is finding the gradient not also a viable way of finding the plane? And if it is, how can I understand that I can exclude the z-component?

Comment: Sure you can find the gradient! The gradient of that function at $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is $(4x_1-1,-5,0)$ and you can use it to find the tangent plane: it is the plane$$(4x_1-1)(x-x_1)-5(y-y_1)=0.$$

Comment: Sweet! Where I fail to understand however is this tangent plane will be tangent to any point $(1,1,a)$, correct? Is this because when computing the gradient, since there is no z-component, $f_z(1,1,a)$ simply turns to zero? I am having a hard time reasoning for that the plane will be tangent to $(1,1,a)$, I want to be able to say "This tangent-plane will be tangent to any point $(1,1,a)$ because of this and this reason.". But I do not understand how to...

Thank you so much for your time, help and patience, much appreciated!!